# Offline cache of the API - for when the developer has no internet.

Tags: support

Is there some fake API program that "simulates" the API? Just I'm going on a long car journey tomorrow, and I won't have an internet connection on my laptop and don't want to waste the whole journey without being able to program, so is there any way of like caching the API so that I can test offline?

Comment: I actually thought about making something like this, but it never materialized :(

Comment: Is there some generic program that can make an offline copy of a website and then make do something to the hosts file to redirect any requests to a local directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the "Map Remote" feature of the Charles proxy to map remote URLs to local files: http://www.charlesproxy.com/

Comment: Thanks, that's amazing! I used it combination with what I answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517765/

Comment: It's also going to be useful for simulating updates to the API, such as new sites, sites changing etc.

Comment: Charles is pretty amazing for a wide variety of use cases. It's so worth the money.

Comment: Especially the throttling, that is useful, both for developing and installing on my brothers computer so he doesn't use all the bandwidth and slow the internet down for everyone else ;)