# Application to read stackoverflow off-line

Tags: discussion, app-request, offline, data-dump

I'm now going on vacation and I won't be having internet connection there, I was thinking it would be a good time to browse throught the stackoverflow data dump. However its all in XML and I'd have to write a client to make it readable. Is there any existing client?

Comment: In case it gets good answers over there, see the [equivalent question on meta/stackoverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/73142/application-to-read-stackoverflow-off-line).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Offline cache of the API - for when the developer has no internet.](http://stackapps.com/questions/1864/offline-cache-of-the-api-for-when-the-developer-has-no-internet)

Comment: There also is [this equivalent question on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398590/6377268)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This app](https://stackapps.com/questions/2652/stack-overflow-offline-pdf-question-reader) can help you in some way. Create some pdf's on the topics you're interested in and off you go.

Answer (score 0):

You could try out [StackStash](http://stackstash.com) . Its our iOS app that lets you browse and search stackoverflow offline.

Comment: The application does not seem to exist anymore – the domain redirects to a domain seller as of now.