# Stack Overflow offline PDF question reader

Tags: app, offline

[image]

#### About

Using a keyword, the [Stackoverflow Offline Reader](http://soofflinereader.codeplex.com) WinForm app loads all the questions
and their answers into a single pdf file and displays the pdf (if you have a reader installed). Questions can be sorted by votes or filtered by keyword in title only.

This app was developed to read questions on any eReader which supports pdf's like the iPad. I also like reading in a top down fashion without using a mouse.

Note: This app was developed before the API, datapump and public database were available.

#### License

Microsoft Public License (Ms-PL).

#### Download

[Stackoverflow Offline Reader](http://soofflinereader.codeplex.com)

#### Platform

Windows (Tested under Windows 7 only)

#### Contact

jentel at hotmail dot com

#### Code

C# - WinForm

Comment: please see http://stackapps.com/questions/7/how-to-list-your-application-library-wrapper-script-here for formatting guidelines

Comment: The formatting has been updated.